# Flutter Web: How to select and drag Scrollbar

Tags: flutter, scrollbar, flutter-web

So with the following code snippet we can have a scrollbar for flutter web apps:

```dart
Scrollbar(
  controller: _scrollController,
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  child: SingleChildScrollView( ...
```

But what about being able to click on it to drag it and scroll faster? Currently it seems its only for display. Is it implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem.

It works properly, no?

[image]

### Full source code:

```dart
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Scrollbar Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _scrollController = useScrollController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scrollbar(
        controller: _scrollController,
        isAlwaysShown: true,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          child: Text(Faker().lorem.sentences(100).join(' ')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The question was about flutter web